# Generate a list of random numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random

So, the assignment is to ask the user for how many randomly generated numbers they want in a list, and then from that list find the: total(sum), the average, the smallest and the largest number.  SOFAR, I am getting an error on line 14 "object of type 'int' has no len()". I get the same responce when using < too.

```
import random


def main():

    randomList = 0    
    smallest = 0
    largest = 0
    average = int(input("How may numbers (between 1-100) would you like to generate?: "))
    total = 0
    if average >= 101 or average <= 0:
        print("Invalid input:How may numbers (between 1-100) would you like to generate?: ")
    else:
         while randomList != len(int(average)):
            randomList.append(random.randint(1,101))
    randomList=sorted(randomList)
    print(randomList)
    total = sum(randomList)
    average = float(sum(randomList)) / max(len(randomList))
    largest = randomList.pop(average)
    smallest = randomList.pop(0)

    print('The total of all the numbers are ',str(total))
    print('The average of all the numbers are ',str(average))
    print('The largest of all the numbers are ',str(largest))
    print('The smallest of all the numbers are ',str(smallest))
main()
```

Comment: you're probably getting the error because you're getting doing `len(int(average))` which is as the error says. might be worth changing you're loop to something else?

Comment: `average` is a numerical number,  you can't apply len on it

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Look at the line of code in question and explain to yourself, in your own, English words, how it is supposed to work. Then break it down, step by step, and explain how it actually does attempt to work as written. Notice the disconnect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version of your code.

```
import random

def main():

    smallest = 0
    largest = 0
    n = int(input("How may numbers (between 1-100) would you like to generate?: "))
    total = 0
    if n >= 101 or n <= 0:
        print("Invalid input:How may numbers (between 1-100) would you like to generate?: ")
    else:
        randomList = random.choices(range(1, 101), k=n)
    print(randomList)
    total = sum(randomList)
    average = sum(randomList) / len(randomList)
    largest = max(randomList)
    smallest = min(randomList)

    print('The total of all the numbers are ',str(total))
    print('The average of all the numbers are ',str(average))
    print('The largest of all the numbers are ',str(largest))
    print('The smallest of all the numbers are ',str(smallest))

main()
```

**Explanation**

Many errors have been fixed:

- Use `random.choices` for a random list of values of specified length.
- You use `average` in the context of a list of numbers and `average` value. Make sure you name and use variables appropriately.
- Sorting is not required for your algorithm.
- I have corrected calculations for `average`, `largest`, `smallest`.

In addition, I advise you get in the habit of returning values via the `return` statement and leave formatting as a step separate from your calculation function.

Comment: I know you mean well, but questions of OP's sort should be discouraged. This is not a good place for people to learn fundamentals of programming, especially not debugging; it is better suited to filling in gaps in domain knowledge. The goal is for third parties to be able to find solutions on SO by searching - every new programmer has subtly different debugging issues, and won't know what to search for anyway beyond the low-hanging fruit ("what's a `FooError`?") that was already well covered years ago.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, On reflection, with a code dump and a few sentences, you're probably right. The problem is SO isn't ready for this yet. It takes far too long for us gold badge holders to close a question (does it need 5 of us, really?), and this is the only way to avoid half a dozen poor / incomplete answers. There have been loads of requests for more power to gold/silver tag badges on Meta, but really nobody cares.

Comment: I do enjoy everyones suggestions and input about where I went wrong.  I do try my hardest to avoid post here unless it's my last resort, and I havent been able to find any other solutions that resemble errors or problems Im having mainly because people do start complaining about how some people use this as thier go to place without doing research on thier own.

Answer (score -2):

how about this:
    randomList = [random.integer() for i in range(userinput)]